# Why does pdfcrop invoke pdftex internally?

Tags: pdftex, pdfcrop

What for does pdfcrop execute pdftex internally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It basically creates a TeX document which includes the original PDF as image(s) while setting the correct clipping parameter to remove the excess space.

You can do something like this manually using the `pdfpages` package (which uses `\includegraphics` internally, see also `grfguide`):

```
\includepdf[fitpaper,clip,trim=<llx> <lly> <urx> <ury>]{file}
```

(here `ll`= lower left, `ur` = upper right)

The `pdfcrop` script however does this manually by apparently adjusted the parameters like `\pdfhorigin`, `\pdfvorigin`, `\pdfpagewidth`, `\pdfpageheight` etc.

The `preview` package can crop documents down to their true bounding box for you. It works great for `pdflatex`, but I didn't got it working for `latex` by myself. The `standalone` class uses this package and also sets all other necessary parameters (like empty page style, etc.) so that a tight PDF image from e.g. a `tikzpicture` is produced.

Comment: Do we need to pass `-interaction=nonstopmode` to `pdfcrop`?

Comment: @xport: I never needed to do this.